# What does 10.0.0.0/32 mean?

Tags: ipv4, ip, subnet, ip-address

I saw two IP addresses that I did not understand.

1. 10.0.0.0/32
2. 10.0.0.255/32

Are these broadcast addresses?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those are host addresses. Addresses using a 32-bit mask only have a single address, and they are addresses that are assigned to a host.

Comment: Is 10.0.0.0 a valid host address regardless of subnet mask? Oh I guess on a subnet of 8.0.0.0/4, or something like that, maybe it is.

Comment: Yes, or `8.0.0.0/6`. You could certainly have a loopback with the `10.0.0.0/32` address, or you could have it as a host address in a larger network. I have heard people insist that any address that has `0` or `255` in the last octet is not a valid host address, even though that really isn't the case.

Comment: That's probably exactly what confused the asker.